# Woocommerce convert simple products to variations

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

With Woocommerce, I am trying to combine already existing simple products into one single variable product.

For Example:

- Simple1 (Color- Red , Size-X) Simple2 (Color- Green ,Size-X)
- To Variable (Color- Red|Green, Size-X)

In Magento, we can create a configurable product and assign simple products to it, but that functionality not exist in Woocommerce. So I am trying to achieve this by custom function. Where admin can select multiple simple products and make those product to variations add assign to Variable product.

In Woocommerce all the products are saved as post with post_type **product**, but variation product alone having post_type '**product_variation**' and parent id of variant product. Can I update this two fields alone? It will be a proper way?

Comment: Hi, Dineshwar rajendran, welcome to [wordpress.se]. Your question may need editing to get the best answers. The downvote is probably because there is not enough context to understand what you trying to do and what you have tried so far. As a quick guide, pretend you are talking to a busy colleague and have to tell them everything they absolutely need to give you a clear answer before they rush away. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to. Also, the community is not overly fond of plugin recommendation requests.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I have made an edit in my question hope it's clear..

Comment: Until I saw the tags, (and because I skipped the heading) I had zero ideas about what you were asking about. Now, I guess this is a woocommerce question but as I am not a mind reader this is still a guess. Try this, I have X set up. I want to achieve Y. I have tried Z but got results foo and bar.

Comment: **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Consider starting by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem and any difficulties in solving it yourself. The first paragraph is the second thing most readers will see, so make it a good one. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.

Comment: I have made an edit, now I tried to explain my problem it's regarding the Woocommerce product create.